# Getting a list of packages updated by `pipenv update`

Tags: pipenv

If I do a `pipenv update` I like to list all the packages and versions that were updated in the git commit. e.g.:

> Packages updated:
>
> - bleach 3.1.4 to 3.1.5
> - boto3 1.12.39 to 1.13.1
> - botocore 1.15.39 to 1.16.1
> - etc...

Is there any way to generate a list like this automatically from pipenv, before, during or after doing an update? The closest I can think of is to do `pipenv update --outdated` first and use that, which I *guess* will be similar?

Just wondering if I'm missing anything else before I write something to parse the output of `git diff Pipfile.lock` to generate the list myself.